# How to get the data from asyncstorage and save in shared preference android native code

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

While I'm migrating the app to react native to Android native.

User details saved using asyncstorage should persist when the apk is updated. How to access the asynchronous deposit from the native Android code?

Thanks.